# Why is the regular expression setminus operator not working for MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select all client names without vowels from a table (should therefore return an empty list) using the setminus operator with regular expressions, but it is simply returning the entire column. The same happens if I try to select all client names without 'a' or 'e' or any other vowel.

This is the query I'm using:

```
select client_name from client

where client_name regexp '[^aeiou]';
```

If I try doing a condition like below, then the inside caret actually does take every character other than 'a'. I'm not sure why it doesn't work by itself though.

```
select client_name from client

where client_name regexp '^[^a]'
```

Expected - empty output

Actual Results - whole column is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression can match anywhere in the name. So it will match any name that has any non-vowel character, not where *all* the characters are not vowels. You need to anchor it and quantify it:

```
WHERE client_name REGEXP '^[^aeiou]*$'
```

This tests *all* the characters in the name.

Or you can negate the test:

```
WHERE client_name NOT REGEXP '[aeiou]'
```

The regexp matches a vowel anywhere in the name. Then using `NOT` makes this return the names that don't match.